# two foreign key in one tables sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

I was making one table that have two foreign key to another tables. But still error in the query.

here the code :

```
    //inialitation attribute
    public static final String TABLE_MATRIKPENDAPAT = "tableMatrikPendapat";
    public static final String MATRIK_IDKRITERIA1 = "matrikIdKriteria1";
    public static final String MATRIK_IDKRITERIA2 = "matrikIdKriteria2";
    public static final String MATRIK_NILAI = "nilaiMatrik";

    //create query

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MATRIKPENDAPAT = "create table "
            + TABLE_MATRIKPENDAPAT + " ("
            + MATRIK_IDKRITERIA1 + " integer , FOREIGN KEY ("+ MATRIK_IDKRITERIA1 +") REFERENCES "
            + TABLE_KRITERIA + " ("+ KRITERIA_ID +"), " 
            + MATRIK_IDKRITERIA2 + " integer , FOREIGN KEY ("+ MATRIK_IDKRITERIA2 +") REFERENCES "
            + TABLE_KRITERIA + " ("+ KRITERIA_ID +"), "
            + MATRIK_NILAI + " integer not null);";
```

And the error said :

```
sqlite.SQLiteException: near "matrikIdKriteria2": syntax error
```

when i make it with with one foreign key, like here :

```
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MATRIKPENDAPAT = "create table "
    + TABLE_MATRIKPENDAPAT + " ("
    + MATRIK_IDKRITERIA1 + " integer , FOREIGN KEY ("+ MATRIK_IDKRITERIA1 +") REFERENCES "
    + TABLE_KRITERIA + " ("+ KRITERIA_ID +"), " 
    + MATRIK_NILAI + " integer not null);";
```

the error said :

> sqlite.SQLiteException: near "nilaiMatrik": syntax error

so I think, my problems there in query after the first foreign key.

what should the correct query ??
Please help me guys

Comment: You didn't include all the constants. Print the SQL to the log, and you'll probably see the problem yourself. But if you don't, post _the SQL code_ that the Java is producing rather than the Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
integer , FOREIGN
```

Should be

```
integer  FOREIGN
```

With the comma it looks like another column.

Here is what I have:

```
   + BookTableMetaData.BOOK_USER_ID + " INTEGER REFERENCES "
   + UserTableMetaData.TABLE_NAME + "("
+ UserTableMetaData._ID + "),"
```

So, to have this work with your set up

```
MATRIK_IDKRITERIA1 + " integer REFERENCES "
+ TABLE_KRITERIA + " ("+ KRITERIA_ID +")
```

This may be enough.

Comment: i was try it, now the error said "sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FOREIGN": syntax error"